# Tensorflow serving ml engine online prediction json file format

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, tensorflow-serving, google-cloud-ml

I would like to save a Tensorflow model to ml-engine on GCP, and to make an online prediction.
I have successfully created the model on the ml-engine, however, I am struggling to make the input JSON string feed into the model.
Here is the [code](https://github.com/karrey05/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow_core.py) and [data](https://github.com/karrey05/tensorflow/blob/master/monthly-milk-production.csv), credit goes to Jose Portilla from his Tensorflow course on Udemy.

I have used gcloud commend for prediction:

> gcloud ml-engine predict --model='lstm_test' --version 'v3' --json-instances ./test.json

test.json content:

> {"inputs":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]}

Errors that I got:

> {
>     "error": "Prediction failed: Error during model execution: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details=\"You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_2' with dtype float and shape [?,12,1]\n\t [[Node: Placeholder_2 = Placeholder_output_shapes=[[?,12,1]], dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,12,1], _device=\"/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0\"]]\")"
>   }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, using an example proto as input is not the preferred method for using the CloudML service. Instead, we'll directly use a placeholder.

Also, generally speaking, you should create a *clean* serving graph, so I would also suggest the following change:

```python
def build_graph(x):
  # All the code shared between training and prediction, given input x
  ...

  outputs = ...

  # Make sure they both have a Saver.    
  saver = tf.train.Saver()

  return outputs, saver

# Do training
with tf.Graph().as_default() as prediction_graph:
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_time_steps, num_inputs])
  outputs, saver = build_graph(x)

with tf.Session(graph=prediction_graph) as sess:
  session.run([tf.local_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])
  saver.restore(session, latest)

# This is a much simpler interface for saving models.
tf.saved_model.simple_save(
    sess,
    export_dir=SaveModel_folder,
    inputs={"x": x},
    outputs={"y": outputs}
)
```

Now, the file you use with `gcloud` should look something like this:

```python
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
[[2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

This sends a batch of two instances (one instance/example per line), and assumes `num_inputs` is 4 and `num_time_steps` is 3.

One more important caveat, gcloud's file format is slightly different than the full body of the request you would send if you were using a traditional client to send a request (e.g. JS, Python, curl, etc.). The body of the request corresponding to the same file above is:

```python
{
  "instances": [
    [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
    [[2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2, 2]]
  ]
}
```

Basically, each line in the `gcloud` file becomes an entry in the "instances" array.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions! I have updated the code on github accordingly and also modified the input JSON file, which has helped me to get further.  However, there are still problems.   I have included the errors in my github issues. @rhaertel80

Comment: I think the problem may be the ml-engine run time version (1.4) being different than training version (1.7), since simple_save is a 1.7 feature.  The code works on gcloud ml-engine local predict. @rhaertel80, do you know what's the timeline for having runtime 1.7 available on ml-engine?

Comment: Probably you should open a new question with the new issue

Comment: mismatched versions frequently cause issues. I believe 1.7 should *unofficially* be available within a week; it may already be available to use.